# How to store non-standard web authentication?

Tags: ios, authentication, asp.net-web-api

In the web API my app communicates with, the authentication process is designed in the following way:

1. The user enters the name of the `group` that he/she belongs to.
2. The server sends the list of group members.
3. The user chooses a `user name` and types a `password`.
4. My app sends a hash constructed of the `group id`, `user id` and `password` to the server to validate the credentials and in case of successful validation uses this hash in further transactions.

Having this process, I do not get standard `NSURLConnection` messages like `connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` or `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`.
I can deal with it per se, but when it comes to *securely storing* the credentials, I get confused. Is there a way to do this via some built-in iOS SDK methods or I have to write the hash in a file manually, for example? What's the proper way?

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is not a good idea. It allows people trying to break in to easily obtain a list of users. Given that list and common password cracking techniques, it's quite likely that a malicious individual will get into your system through one of those ids. I don't know of any website that offers this style of logon because of that. You should reconsider your design.

Comment: @Derek, thanks for your consideration! I'll show this to the API developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keychain seems the best option to store the user's credentials/hash.
Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

And https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/05e64ff2814a8192c43f1f81eb8e09dc3764fa18/security

- Be aware that while the keychain is probably the safest place in iOS to store this kind of data, it isn't entirely secure.  But considering the data you want to store, it's probably well enough.

Edit: Look at http://overhrd.com/?p=208
You'd be able to access the data on your keychain with simple calls of this nature:

```
[Keychain setString:@"hashhashhash" forKey:@"userHash"];

// later on…
[Keychain getStringForKey:@"userHash"];
```

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit?

Comment: The keychain let you store data and take care of securing it (encrypted, and relatively secure [once a device has been lost or stolen, there is little way to guarantee the total safety of it's content, even encrypted.]). It isn't as simple to use as NSUserDefaults to begin with, but a lot of sample code exists.  I edited my message to add another, more appropriate to your problem (since you just want to store one hash), code sample.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate this